# Run python script with droneapi without terminal

Tags: python-2.7, dronekit-python, dronekit

I managed to run examples in command prompt after running mavproxy.py and loading droneapi. But when I double click on on my script, it throws me "'local_connect' is not defined", it runs in terminal as was told above, but I cannot run it only with double click. So my question is: Is there any way to run script using droneapi only with double click?

using Windows 8.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the [Running an App/Example](http://python.dronekit.io/guide/getting_started.html#running-an-app-example) section of the guide. For now, you can only run a DroneKit script by launching it from inside the MAVProxy terminal. For example, after launching:

```
$ mavproxy.py --master=127.0.0.1:14550
MANUAL> module load droneapi.module.api
 DroneAPI loaded
```

You can use the `api start` command to run a local script:

```
MANUAL> api start vehicle_state.py
STABILIZE>

 Get all vehicle attribute values:
  Location:  Attitude: Attitude:pitch=-0.00405988190323,yaw=-0.0973932668567,roll=-0.00393210304901
  Velocity: [0.06, -0.07, 0.0]
  GPS: GPSInfo:fix=3,num_sat=10
  groundspeed: 0.0
  airspeed: 0.0
  mount_status: [None, None, None]
  Mode: STABILIZE
  Armed: False
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Sony Nguyen is asking for running the vehicle_state.py outside the Mavproxy command prompt, just like runnning the .py file normally.

I'm also looking for a solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can only run dronekit from mavproxy at the moment (its structured as a mavproxy module, there are plans to restructure it), however if you simply want to avoid having to load up MavProxy and then running code manually, you can use the `cmd` flag:

```
mavproxy.py --cmd="api start app.py"
```